# SAX - HTML attribute with no value

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

I am currently using SAX to parse some HTML.
However, I now have to a parse a document that has something like this:

```
`<OPTION VALUE="123" SELECTED>`
```

and because SELECTED does not have an actual value set, it is throwing an error (not well-formed, invalid token).  Is there a way to resolve this so I can keep using SAX?

My code:

```
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        xr.setContentHandler(sch);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(Statics.SUBJECT_CODE_URL);
        xr.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SAX to parse HTML.  HTML is not XML.  A perfectly valid HTML document is NOT a valid XML document, and nothing you can do will make an XML parser parse it.

Answer (score 0):

With SAX you could parse XHTML, but you cannot parse HTML with a great success, because HTML is not a well-formed XML.